# Unable to access this keyword property inside a vuejs promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Am performing an async validation where i need to access the $axios set globally in vuejs but this fails

```
    Validator.extend('async_validate_job_type', {
    getMessage: field => `The Name already exists`,
    validate: value => new Promise((resolve) => {
        //validate email.
        this.$axios.post('/validate/position-type', {email:value})
            .then(
               ....perform stuff here
            )

    })
});
```

Now the above throws an error

```
cannot read propery post of undefined
```

In other components using `this.$axios.post` works. But in the above seems i cannot access this.$axios. Where am i going wrong?

I have already setup axios via

```
Vue.prototype.$axios =  axios.create(axiosConfig);
```

Also using normal function like this also fails

```
    Validator.extend('async_validate_job_type', {
    getMessage: field => `The Name already exists`,
    validate(value){
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
          console.log("value of this is", this); //this is undefined
          this.$axios.post())


      })
    }
});
```

Comment: I would just axios to `window`, rather than adding in to the Vue prototype. However, I would guess that you have a scoping issue and that `this` is actually referring to window and not a Vue instance. Try using a normal function instead: `validate(value) { return new Promise(...)}`

Comment: calling this inside a normal function also fails

Comment: @craig_h ive updated the question withnnormal function try which also fails

Answer (score -3):

To add something in VueComponent instance use mixins:

```
Vue.mixin({
  beforeCreate: function () {
    this.$axios = axios.create(axiosConfig);
  }
});
```

Doc:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4y0ftc51/